# Message task for xbuild in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, xamarin.ios, continuous-integration, xbuild

I am trying to implement Continuous Integration using the xbuild in Xamarin. I know xbuild uses .csproj file to compile the application. I wanted to print the value of the variables 'IpaPackagePath' and 'OutputPath' from the csproj file. I think (?) that xbuild would be similar to msbuild. In msbuild the method to print the values is by using Message task
the following the portion of the file

```
    <PropertyGroup>
           <CreateIpaDependsOn>
           $(CreateIpaDependsOn);
            DisplayMessages
           </CreateIpaDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="DisplayMessages">
        <Message Text="IPAPACKAGEPATH = $(IpaPackagePath)" />
        <Message Text="OUTPUTPATH = $(OutputPath)" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CopyIpa"
        Condition="'$(OutputType)' == 'Exe'
            And '$(ComputedPlatform)' == 'iPhone'
            And '$(BuildIpa)' == 'true'">
        <Copy
            SourceFiles="$(IpaPackagePath)"
            DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)"/>    
    </Target>
```

I dont find any messages printed on the console or any target name 'DisplayMessages' executed.
**What I am getting wrong?**

**Or is there any method to print the values of the variables in the xbuild ?**

Answer (score 0):

I use `Message Text` within `xbuild` (and the OS-X version of `msbuild`).

Make sure that your `/verbosity:` is set to at least `minimal` as `quiet` will suppress `Message Text` output.

#### Usage Example:

```
xbuild /p:SolutionDir=~/ /target:VIEWENV Droid/Realm080.Droid.csproj
```

#### Target Example:

```
<!--    PlayScript   -->
<Target Name="VIEWENV" DependsOnTargets="BeforeResolveReferences">
    <Message Text="                          CscToolExe: $(CscToolExe) "/>
    <Message Text="                         CscToolPath: $(CscToolPath) "/>
    <Message Text="                       ReferencePath: $(ReferencePath) "/>
    <Message Text="                           ToolsPath: $(ToolsPath) "/>
    <Message Text="            TargetFrameworkDirectory: $(TargetFrameworkDirectory) "/>
~~~
</Target>
```

Note: Existing either in a `.target` file that is referenced in your `.csproj` or directly included in the `.csproj`:

#### Example Output:

```
VIEWENV:
                            CscToolExe: mcs.exe
                           CscToolPath:
                         ReferencePath:
                             ToolsPath:
```

Comment: Where I need to set the '/verbosity'  option ?

Comment: `xbuild /verbosity:XXXXX` levels are quiet, minimal, normal, detailed, diagnostic

Comment: <Message Text="foo" Importance="high"> it will display in the output even if you have the verbosity on quiet.